# Need to run a job at a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to create a job in order to send a notification to a Twilio call, therefore it is important to have a robust solution that can make sure jobs are run at a specific time (I don't think being put into a queue is accurate enough).

What is the best solution for this type of a task?

These notifications need to happen at a specific time in the call. Such as "1 minute left". Therefore it needs to be able to:

1. Run at arbitrary times (1:22PM or 2:45AM)
2. Be defined by user input (they set the time of the call)

(It would be nice if that solution could run on Heroku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific case that you have mentioned, I think that you should give delayed_job a try:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#readme

it has a run_at option where you can specify the time at which you want to run the job.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Heroku `cron` to run jobs either daily or hourly.

Daily cron is free, hourly cron costs $3/month: http://addons.heroku.com/cron.

Typically `cron` runs when you first initiate it (i.e. if you set it up at 3pm, it'll run at 3pm every day), but you can change that by sending an e-mail to support@heroku.com.

To run code in a cron, add your code to a `cron.rake` file and check out the cron docs [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron).

#### FYI

Heroku's own samples for cron suggest doing a time check, i.e.

```
if Time.now.hour % 4 == 0 # run every four hours
  ...
```

But, if you are running a daily cron, the code will run at a time that is likely to **fail** the above conditional. So, unless you are paying for hourly cron and you only want it to run *specific* hours, leave out that part of their sample code and just include your own code normally.

### Running at Specific Times

Try `delayed_job`'s `:run_at` column, which may give you the flexibility you need to run jobs at very specific times.

Heroku Docs: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job

Comment: This doesn't work if I'm trying to do a notification in a call. Needs to be able to run by the minute (I'll update my question to be more clear)

Comment: FYI -- the add-on referenced in this answer is now referred to as [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a cronjob for that. If you are on a Linux box then you can add a cron to the crontab and specify the time at which it runs. It is very flexible. You can find the details here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

If you want to do it in a ruby way, try whenever gem:
https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Doesn't that require that you know the time before hand? Or can you arbitrarily set it up?

Comment: If you want to run the cron at arbitrary times, then you can write another cron that keeps on updating the crontab with the new arbitrary times. The cron that updates the crontab should be running more frequently, say every 1 min or 5 min and it adds an entry for the new arbitrary time. You will have to write another cron for cleaning up the crontab (crons which have executed), and it can run once every day. I hope you get the approach.

Comment: The above approach should be followed if you have no idea when the cron is going to run, and the time is generated somewhere from the code. If you can decide that it runs on the 7th day,2nd hour of each month, etc etc then you should look at the cron examples. They are very very flexible and you could achieve any time using different combinations. Probably you need to relook at your approach. You could dump all these entries to a table with a timestamp(when to execute), and a cron runs every 1 min and sends notifications where (timestamp - Time.now) < threshold. Threshold could also be in db.

Answer (score 0):

Goto cron jobs in your hosting control panel